# First background image is sharp, second one is not

Tags: html, css

I have two different divs with the same css properties and `background-image`. However the `background-image` is displaying well on the first div, but not sharp enough on the other.

Comment: please add your code and what you tried so far

Comment: They're same. Because Your picture quality is low.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `transform` property. I've used it for vertical centering and it blurred the children's `background-image`. After removing the transform, the background image is sharp well.